# как правильно научить нейроную сети понимать что ноутбук разряжается без keras только numpy

Tags: python

хочу сделать простую нейронную сети для прогнозирования что ноутбук разряжается на основе двух значении на уровне заряда и подключена ли зарядка

в сети я подаю два значения 20 и 0 или 1 20 процент заряда 0 нет зарядки 1 есть зарядка

но у меня не получается её обучить правильно она каждый раз не правильно дает ответ

когда я делал такую самую сети на "keras" там оно как-то само все делало и все было правильно там я использовал в качестве функции потерь бинарную кросс энтропию и функцию активации "сигмоида" и оптимизатор "адам" я хочу сделать такую самую нейронную сети без "keras" что-бы лучшее понять как работает алгоритм обучения "back propagation" но у меня не получается как я не делал если вы хорошо понимаете работу алгоритма подскажите что я не так делаю буду признателен по я новичок в этой теме и учу все это и за любопытства к нейронным сетям

вот весь код который я сделал на примере кода который переписал из видео на ютубе

```
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

connection = sqlite3.connect('c:/users/fasmon/desktop/python/ai_test/lib/site-packages/dataset.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM DATASET')
dataset = cursor.fetchall()

weights1 = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,[2,2])
weights2 = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,[2])

count = len(dataset)
N = 100000
alpha = 0.1

for i in range(N):
    index = np.random.randint(0,count)
    x = dataset[index][0:2]
    c = dataset[index][-1]

    suma = np.dot(weights1,x)
    out1 = sigmoid(suma)

    suma = np.dot(weights2,out1)
    out2 = sigmoid(suma)

    e = out2 - c
    delta = e * derivative(out2)

    weights2[0] -= delta * alpha * out1[0]
    weights2[1] -= delta * alpha * out1[1]

    delta = delta * weights2 * derivative(out1)

    weights1[0] -= delta[0] * alpha * np.array(x)
    weights1[1] -= delta[1] * alpha * np.array(x)

x = np.array([20,0])
suma = np.dot(weights1,x)
out1 = sigmoid(suma)

suma = np.dot(weights2,out1)
print(sigmoid(suma))

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```